# Attaching Time to a field oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am looking for something like attaching the Time(Hour,Minute,AM/PM) to my form field like We attach a calendar to a field.
I have the template fmb and in it there is a Canvas(CALENDAR_TIME) which has the fields like HOUR,MINUTE.
Can I use it for my field ? and how ?

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance